# which queue should I use (App Engine)

Tags: google-app-engine, cron, google-api-java-client, google-tasks-api, google-tasks

I have app engine application. I have users  refresh tokens (In order to have access to google drive) in my database.

**Now, I want to create this:**

Every week (I mean every 7th day), I want to temorary download **users** PDF **documents** from google drive and work with them. I send mails to each user  about their pdf documents.

The main problem is that , there might be many users. and each user may have a lot of document too.  I should do that work for each users, once a week. But each users data needs much time too.

**QUESTION:**
So, now I think, which time service should I use? Cron  or Task Queue. and why? and if Task Queue, which one. which will be faster, and flexible? I can send mail to the user later too (it's not necessary to send mails immediately when she/he requests)

**QUESTION2:** can I run Task Queue , for instance, once a week?

For example If I want to run it every day I can use something like that:

```
<rate>1/d</rate>
```

but how can I do that once a week?

**QUESTION3:** because of there might be many user (and because of each user needs much time), can I use something like that?

CRON job will be weekly (once a week).  And CRON to call TASK QUEUSE, for each user. Each user data will be downloaded in the app engine server temporary (I think , If I save it in memory, it will be very hard for server). Then I will see PDF documents and send mails to each user. Is this good way? or should I use only CRON? did I have limitation here? On server storage or at queues or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use both. Create a [cron job](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron) to run every 7 days. Have the cron job fire a task (in the [push queue](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-push)) to process your PDFs. I'd use a separate task for each PDF to process, and [configure your queue.yaml](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/queue#Python_Defining_push_queues_and_processing_rates) so that it processes them at the correct rate (depending on budget / rate limiting factors etc).

If you need to send mail, you can do this from the task request, via the [mail api](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/).

As a side note, if you have many users, a better approach may be to have the cron job run more frequently than every 7 days (say, once a day, or even more). You can use logic to determine which users need to be processed each time the cron runs. This may even the load, and ultimately save you money.

Comment: One user, may have  10, or 50 pdf document. should I separate tasks for each PDF to precess OR  seperate tasks for the PDFs of each users?

Comment: It largely depends on what you are doing with the PDFs, but I think the more robust approach would be to have a separate task for each PDF. To do this, you will need a monitor task to keep check on progress of the other tasks. The Pipeline API has this type of functionality built in -> https://code.google.com/p/appengine-pipeline/